# Insert data from 3 array

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have 3 arrays with data from input form. Now I have to insert that data in a database.

My arrays are as following:

```
1st-NAME  - a,b,c
2nd-ADDRESS- x,y,z
3rd-MOBILE-1,2,3
```

Now i have to add these in table like below:

[image]

How can I do this in Laravel? I have worked with 2 arrays using array_combine but how to do it for 3 arrays?

Comment: just loop over the arrays? It's hard without seeing your code

Comment: use array_merge

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of Laravel collections and `zip` method. Assuming you have `Table` model your for table and added `name`, `address` and `mobile` to `$fillable` property of `Table` model, you can do it like so:

```
$names = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$addresses = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
$mobiles = [1, 2, 3];

collect($names)->zip($addresses, $mobiles)->map(function ($record) {
    return [
        'name' => $record[0],
        'address' => $record[1],
        'mobile' => $record[2],
    ];
})->each(function ($record) {
    Table::create($record);
});
```